# File search recursivly in the folders on windows

Tags: perl

Trying to write a script which search for two file in the folders once those files get found then it has to perform some operation on an another file :

**I am using windows for this script.**

**Below is the hierarchy for folders :**

```
                      Logs
                     / | \  
                 abc   def   xyz
                 / \   / \     /\
               ANR etc ANR etc ANR etc
```

**etc= text files.**

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to check ANR folder whether two files(pqr.txt and rst.txt) are there or not, if those files are there then do operation on etc, like i have to read one  specific  text file and search for some keywords in that particular  text file.

**How am i approaching:**

```
#!/bin/usr/perl -w
use strict; 
use Cwd; 
use File::Find; 
my $dir ="C:\APTscripts\APStress\Logs";

find(\&file_operation,$dir);

$first_file = @ARGV[0];
$sec_file= @ARGV[1];

sub file_operation
{
    my $file = $_;
    if(($file =~ /teaces/) && ($file =~ /traces.txt.bugreport/))
    {
        Do some opeartion 
    }
}
```

But with this logic i  am not able to do whatever i ma trying to do. can any body help me out in this.

Comment: What problem are you having? We can't help unless you explain your problem.

Comment: Backslashes are special in double quotes. Use single quotes or forward slashes for paths.

Comment: @ Jim .. i can reach till ANR folder and check for those two file but once i checked that those two file are there then how would come from the folder and do the operation on the file which is out side the ANR folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one checks the parent folder according to your description:

```
sub file_operation {
    my $file = File::Spec->rel2abs($_);
    if(($file =~ /traces/) && ($file =~ /traces.txt.bugreport/)) {
        my ($parent) = ($file =~ m!(.*)/!);
        if (-f "$parent/ANR/pqr.txt" or -f "$parent/ANR/rst.txt") {
            print "Do some opeartion: $file $parent\n";
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: `my $file = $File::Find::name;` will yield the absolute path as well. Not sure about cross-platform compatibility though.

Comment: @ Perreal .. my ($parent) = ($file =~ '(.*)/');  i am getting error here ..  i tried with  my ($parent) = ($file =~ /(.*)/); then it was working .. so m i doing right ?